# Task.Run vs Invoke() difference

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, async-await, invoke

I need to pass an argument of type `Task` to some function that is not presented here. Inside the function this task will be executed in async way. If there a difference between these three ways to pass it:

1.

```
Task.Run((Func<Task>)(async () => Foo = await OperateAsync(id)))
```

2.

```
Task.Run(async () => Foo = await OperateAsync(id))
```

3.

```
((Func<Task>)(async () => Foo = await OperateAsync(id))).Invoke()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

1 and 2 differ in which overload of `Task.Run` gets called. The latter passes through the result.

1 and 2 force `OperateAsync` to the thread pool, 3 doesn't, which can be very visible depending on other details. For example, in desktop applications, if `OperateAsync` ends up accessing UI elements, it must not be called using `Task.Run`.

Comment: Is second approach is better than first in terms of performance?

Comment: @AsValeO It should be the same. If either is measurably faster, I think that's a missed opportunity for the other. If you were asking because of the delegate construction, keep in mind that that happens implicitly in the second one as well.